# Connection with mysql openshift

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, tomcat7

I'm using Jpa for connection with MySql in host OpenShift but i geting wrong in URL link connection. here are my percistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="tarifa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.com.falecom.falemais.entity.Tarifa</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

There are link connection provided by OpenShift

```
jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"/>
```

then i getting this error

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}"'.
Error Code: 0
```

My app setting Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0), MySQL 5.5

**How should be the configuration corret?**

Comment: Why did you tag it php?

Comment: sorry i dont see, i remove now